# keytool -list -printcert -jarfile ./myapk.apk gives me Not a signed jar file

Tags: android

When I run the following command on my apk 
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile ./myapk.apk

I get this as output:
  Not a signed jar file

I have already signed my apk with the key still it gives me this error

Comment: How did you sign your APK?

Comment: I added an encrypted key of the keystore format and protected it with a password through my gradle file.

Comment: My jar file is MD5 signed is it : https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/oracle-to-block-jar-files-signed-with-md5-starting-with-april-2017/  this issue? If yes then how to resolve it?

Comment: How did you generate the signed APK?

Comment: Through the generate signed apk feature in android studio. Is unsigned jar and unsigned apk two different terms?

Answer (score 2):

You have to sign your apk with Jar Signature (V1).

1. Go to Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK... > Next (module selected would be your module, most often called "app")
2. Choose APK
3. Next enter Key store details and click Next. (If you don't have any Key store, you can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) tutorial.)
4. Choose debug or release and check V1 (Jar Signature) as shown below and click Finish.

   [image: V1]

Comment: you should display more information about the solution you mentioned such as where to find this options.

Answer (score 2):

`gradle signingReport` task will give you wished results :)

Comment: fix please ./gradlew signingReport